# Green Divergence Theorem Application

Tags: vector-fields

Please how can I use Green Ostrogradsky's Theorem to get the expression of the divergence in cylindrical coordinates?
The thing is how can I equate a double integral to a triple and where will the partial derivatives come from?
Thanks

Comment: Look into any vector analysis text books.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?